# O que fazer com perguntas sem resposta aceita?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado, resposta-aceita

Na minha opinião, um grande problema são questões em aberto que possuem várias respostas. Acredito que as mesmas não passem credibilidade, porque OP não credita a melhor resposta, ficando uma lacuna se ter alguma resposta para a sua pergunta. O que poderíamos fazer para solucionar tal problema? Criar alguma regra de tempo, por exemplo, 1 semana sem interação o moderador possa checar a melhor resposta?

Comment: Não entendi bem qual é o problema e qual é a proposta, poderia escrever em outras palavras ou dar mais informações?

Comment: O que você não entendeu @bigown

Comment: Se o OP não marcou uma resposta certa, a comunidade vai decidir a melhor resposta através dos votos. Qual a **necessidade** de ter alguma resposta marcada correta?

Comment: Concordo @GuilhermeBernal, eu mesmo as vezes deixo algumas perguntas sem resposta aceite, pelo simples facto de achar que nenhuma das respostas é a correta.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, a questão é: será que as resposta com mais votos são as corretas ? acredito que não, nem sempre, e a comunidade muitas vezes é maria vai com as outras. Então, respeito seu ponto de vista, mas, não acredito que isso possa ser a realidade.

Comment: @JorgeB. isso são em poucos casos, eu to dizendo a massa, a maior parte, o todo, tem repostas boas sem crédito, porque, o OP sumiu, largou de mão, volta depois de um mês, e o meu intuito com a questão é, indagar um problema no inicio do SOpt, será que é benéfico?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal se uma pergunta não tem resposta aceita, não podemos usá-la como referência para fechar outras perguntas como duplicatas.

Comment: @Renan se colocou um posicionamento que concordo.

Answer (score 7):

A presença de uma resposta aceita indica que o autor da pergunta considerou aquela resposta a melhor entre as que foram dadas. Isso é o que o site espera que aconteça. Também é muito comum, e até esperado, que a resposta eleita pelo autor seja também a mais votada pela comunidade.

Mas nem sempre é o caso. Às vezes a comunidade vota em massa em outra resposta, e/ou vota contra a escolhida pelo autor. Mesmo assim, a opinião do o autor da pergunta é respeitada, e a resposta aceita fica no topo. Outras vezes nenhuma resposta é aceita, seja porque o autor da pergunta não voltou mais, ou porque não sabe como aceitar uma resposta, ou porque não quis aceitar uma resposta, ou porque esqueceu... Nesse caso prevalece a opinião da comunidade, e a resposta mais votada fica no topo.

O *ideal* é que que toda pergunta tenha uma resposta aceita. A aceitação estimula a postagem de respostas (porque vale `+15`) e indica comprometimento com o site por parte do usuário que aceitou. Sem aceitação, menos pessoas vão responder, e falta de aceitação pode significar alguém que não voltará ao site, ou que pelo menos não se comprometerá com a comunidade. A comunidade sai enfraquecida, e o conteúdo do site sofre por consequência.

Então a falta de resposta aceita pode ser perigosa, mas só se for muito frequente. Se for ocasional, é esperada, e é só uma estatística. Pode irritar quem não teve sua resposta aceita, mas não faz tanto mal ao site como um todo. Acontece, tem usuário que pergunta e some. [Como disse o Guilherme Bernal](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-abertas-a-muito-tempo-com-varias-respostas#comment4051_1479), se o autor não aceita, a comunidade indica a melhor resposta por meio de votos. Não há necessidade de intervenção de moderadores.

Comment: Eu jurava ter visto as respostas com mais votos aparecendo por cima da resposta aceita... ou foi miragem ou um teste no sistema. *Anyway, related: [Can we exempt downvoted accepted answers from getting the top spot?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189424/185667)*

Comment: @brasofilo Se o autor da resposta aceita é o mesmo da pergunta e tem outra resposta melhor votada, esta última fica no topo. Ou isso, ou você reordenou as respostas por data ou atividade.

Comment: Quase nunca ordeno por data/atividade... Mas não sabia dessa exceção, é bem capaz então.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta @bfavaretto, mas, eu vi contra pontos na sua resposta que justificam a minha questão, tipo: `O ideal é que que toda pergunta tenha uma resposta aceita.` e `Então a falta de resposta aceita pode ser perigosa, mas só se for muito frequente.`, é nesse ponto chave que a minha pergunta tem o seu foco.

Comment: @HarryPotter Quando eu disse "ideal", estou falando de algo inatingível, nunca teremos 100% de respostas aceitas. O site é jovem ainda, e se ele continuar indo bem ganharemos mais usuários fixos e menos gente que pinga aqui e some. Então acho cedo pra considerar isso um problema grave. Você tem visto muitas perguntas sem resposta aceita? Sabe de casos de gente desistindo de participar (responder) por causa disso?

Comment: @bfavaretto eu acredito que problema não tem tamanho, é problema, mas, respeito a sua opinião. Tem usuários que já vi até hoje 4 na minha conta, mas, eu coloquei de um modo geral, e como de sempre para manter a ética não vou fazer indicações de nomes, é um assunto a debater e ter a opinião de vocês.

Comment: Claro @HarryPotter, você tem todo o direito de discordar. Vamos esperar por mais gente opinando. E esta pergunta pode muito bem ficar sem resposta aceita :)